# Ionic Capacitor how to use cordova plugins that works on platform browser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

There are some Cordova plugins that doesn't work with ionic serve. We need to add a platform browser to use such plugins. I have just migrated my app from Cordova to capacitor. Now I am unable to use such Cordova plugins with capacitor. I also tried browser API but no solution.

My question is simple. How to use Cordova plugins that runs on platform browser in capacitor.

Thank you in advance.